# How can we enable ui:button in lightning controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, ui

```
var btn = event.getSource();  
btn.disabled = false;  
btn.disabled.set(false);  
btn.attributes.disabled = false;
```

Comment: This is not a question. What is the expected behavior? What do you observe? Do you get an error? If so, please **[edit]** your post to include it verbatim.

Comment: I disagree Adrian, and closing this is a bit heavy handed.  In any case, this works: `component.find('theButtonId').set('v.disabled', true);` BUT only if you have disabled defined as an attribute on your button as so `<lightning:input aura:id="theButtonId" label="theButton" disabled="false" />`

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for:

```
var btn = event.getSource();
btn.set('v.disabled', false);
```